# Fit sideways table in latex on one page

Tags: tables, sidewaystable

I can not fit this sideways table on one page in latex

can I ask for any advice?

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{lllrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
         & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{CNN}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{CNN-2-opt}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{PMSOM}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{PMSOM\^3}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Instance}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Optimum}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{sec1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\% rozdíl}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\%TPDB}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{sec1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\% rozdíl}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\%TPDB}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{k*}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{sec1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\% rozdíl}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\%TPDB}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{k*}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{sec1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\% rozdíl}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{\%TPDB}} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{pr1002} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{259 045} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14.273} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20.53} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.931} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{33.344} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5.64} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.881} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{31.921} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5.93} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.892} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{34.321} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5.12} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1.758} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{u1060} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{224 090} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{30.490} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{23.17} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7.064} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{49.656} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7.25} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.599} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{35.080} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6.37} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.233} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{35.661} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5.92} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.110} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{d1291} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{50 801} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{30.821} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{19.37} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5.971} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{52.841} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6.97} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.682} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{39.361} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11.52} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4.534} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{59.884} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11.11} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6.653} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{fl1400} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{20 127} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{36.658} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{27.73} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10.167} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{155.551} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6.56} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10.202} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{69.672} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.53} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5.943} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{119.912} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{12.00} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{14.387} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{u1432} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{152 970} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{39.821} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{21.66} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{8.625} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{79.033} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.17} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7.249} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{39.354} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5.42} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.135} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{60.751} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5.50} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.343} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{fl1577} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{22 202} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{55.642} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20.25} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11.268} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{92.012} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4.77} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4.389} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{70.191} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3.34} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.344} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{112.847} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11.36} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{12.822} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{u1817} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{57 201} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{81.145} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{17.29} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{14.031} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{162.584} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.49} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{13.800} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{91.843} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.67} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7.965} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{82.310} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.52} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7.839} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{u2152} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{64 253} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{122.003} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{19.06} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{23.253} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{266.852} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{8.61} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{22.971} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{80.121} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.51} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7.620} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{92.781} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{9.94} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9.219} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{u2319} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{234 256} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{159.091} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14.79} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{23.522} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{325.713} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4.14} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{13.479} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{105.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.15} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2.262} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{123.091} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2.46} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3.025} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{pr2392} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{378 032} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{181.002} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{21.36} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{38.667} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{429.660} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7.55} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{32.447} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{131.941} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5.88} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{7.753} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{129.411} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7.04} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9.111} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{pcb3038} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{137 694} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{349.350} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{21.71} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{75.858} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{956.331} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6.66} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{63.661} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{175.729} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7.93} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{13.943} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{231.348} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{7.51} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{17.368} \\
    \midrule
    1) stanoveno jako průměr z 10 měření &      &      & 20.63 & 20.12 &      & 6.89 & 16.12 &      &      & 6.84 & 5.33 &      &      & 7.95 & 7.97 \\
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{2) dle nejlepší hodnoty z 10 měření} &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &  \\
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{3) T = 100} &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{sidewaystable}%
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:latex3].

Comment: sorry - my mistake

Comment: Also, we perfer example code to be full (but minimal) examples,, that we can copy as is to test your issue. Here we have to guess, and we might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by making your table more legible by removing all unnecessary `multicomns` and then use | \small` This fits nicely into one page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
{\small\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt} 
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
         & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{CNN}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{CNN-2-opt}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{PMSOM}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{PMSOM\^3}} \\
    Inst & Opt & sec1 & \% roz. & \% TPDB & sec1 & \% roz. & \% TPDB & k* & sec1 & \% roz & \% TPDB & k* & sec1 & \% roz. & \% TPDB \\
    \midrule
    pr1002 & 259 045 & 14.273 & 20.53 & 2.931 & 33.344 & 5.64 & 1.881 & 3 & 31.921 & 5.93 & 1.892 & 3 & 34.321 & 5.12 & 1.758 \\
    u1060 & 224 090 & 30.490 & 23.17 & 7.064 & 49.656 & 7.25 & 3.599 & 3 & 35.080 & 6.37 & 2.233 & 3 & 35.661 & 5.92 & 2.110 \\
    d1291 & 50 801 & 30.821 & 19.37 & 5.971 & 52.841 & 6.97 & 3.682 & 4 & 39.361 & 11.52 & 4.534 & 4 & 59.884 & 11.11 & 6.653 \\
    fl1400 & 20 127 & 36.658 & 27.73 & 10.167 & 155.551 & 6.56 & 10.202 & 4 & 69.672 & 8.53 & 5.943 & 4 & 119.912 & 12.00 & 14.387 \\
    u1432 & 152 970 & 39.821 & 21.66 & 8.625 & 79.033 & 9.17 & 7.249 & 4 & 39.354 & 5.42 & 2.135 & 4 & 60.751 & 5.50 & 3.343 \\
    fl1577 & 22 202 & 55.642 & 20.25 & 11.268 & 92.012 & 4.77 & 4.389 & 4 & 70.191 & 3.34 & 2.344 & 4 & 112.847 & 11.36 & 12.822 \\
    u1817 & 57 201 & 81.145 & 17.29 & 14.031 & 162.584 & 8.49 & 13.800 & 4 & 91.843 & 8.67 & 7.965 & 4 & 82.310 & 9.52 & 7.839 \\
    u2152 & 64 253 & 122.003 & 19.06 & 23.253 & 266.852 & 8.61 & 22.971 & 5 & 80.121 & 9.51 & 7.620 & 5 & 92.781 & 9.94 & 9.219 \\
    u2319 & 234 256 & 159.091 & 14.79 & 23.522 & 325.713 & 4.14 & 13.479 & 5 & 105.000 & 2.15 & 2.262 & 5 & 123.091 & 2.46 & 3.025 \\
    pr2392 & 378 032 & 181.002 & 21.36 & 38.667 & 429.660 & 7.55 & 32.447 & 5 & 131.941 & 5.88 & 7.753 & 5 & 129.411 & 7.04 & 9.111 \\
    pcb3038 & 137 694 & 349.350 & 21.71 & 75.858 & 956.331 & 6.66 & 63.661 & 5 & 175.729 & 7.93 & 13.943 & 5 & 231.348 & 7.51 & 17.368 \\
%    \midrule
%    1) stanoveno jako prumer z 10 merení &      &      & 20.63 & 20.12 &      & 6.89 & 16.12 &      &      & 6.84 & 5.33 &      &      & 7.95 & 7.97 \\
%    \multicolumn{3}{l}{2) dle nejlepsi hodnoty z 10 mereni} &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &  \\
%    \multicolumn{3}{l}{3) T = 100} &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{sidewaystable}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your table probably fit into text width since you delete problematic last rows of OP table ...

Comment: @Zarko You(re right. I just wanted to clean the code first.